# React-native making Api GET request using axios

Tags: react-native, axios

I'm trying to make API GET request using the youTube API key and the axios lib,
for some reason, I'm getting "Request failed with code 400" when I'm trying to search a term.
For now the term is hardcoded.

```
import axios from 'axios';

const KEY='AIzaSy...';

export default axios.create({
    baseURL:'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3',
    headers:{
        part:'snippet',
        type:'video',
        maxResults: 5,
        key:KEY
    }
});
```

The function that will execute when the user press on submit:

```
    const handelSearch = async ()=>{
        const response = await youTube.get('/search',{
            params:{
                q:'dog'
            }
        })
        setItems(response.data.items);
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
export default axios.create({
  baseURL:'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3',
});

const handelSearch = async ()=>{
  const response = await youTube.get('/search',{
      params:{
        part:'snippet',
        type:'video',
        maxResults: 5,
        key:KEY,
        q:'dog'
      }
  })
  setItems(response.data.items);
};
```

you have to remove the headers from axios create and then move all for the params

and be sure that your key is correct